# I can't lock my MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

I have a (for me) strange problem. I try to lock a set of tables for a transaction that I am trying to do. But for some reason at least one of my tables wont lock.

The code I have looks like this, please remeber it's only the locks that I have problems with currently but all comments are appreciated :)

For some reason ba_flight doesnt get locked or thats the problem i most commonly have, however if I call just:
LOCK TABLES ba_flight it goes perfectly fine.

```
-- SESSION A


-- Part 1 ba_flight

-- UNLOCK TABLES;
START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES ba_booking WRITE,
            ba_paid_booking WRITE,
            ba_passenger WRITE,
            ba_contact WRITE,
            ba_weekday_factor READ,
            ba_plane READ,
            ba_flight READ,
            ba_flight AS ba_f READ,
            ba_weekly_schedule AS ba_ws READ,
            ba_weekly_schedule READ;

-- ba_flight does not get locked


-- 1: Create the booking.
CALL new_booking(1, 6);

SHOW ERRORS;

COMMIT;

SET @bid = get_uncomplete_booking();

SELECT id
  FROM ba_booking
 WHERE contact_id IS NULL;

SELECT @bid AS "BID";

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12341234,
        'Göran',
        'Greenleaf');

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12351235,
        'Adam',
        'Jönsson');

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12361236,
        'Niklas',
        'of Gondor');

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12371237,
        'Erik',
        'Grey');

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12381238,
        'Johan',
        'Baggins');

INSERT INTO ba_passenger(booking_id,
                         ssn,
                         fname,
                         lname)
VALUES (@bid,
        12381238,
        'Elof',
        'Baggins');

-- IF THIS IS FALSE THEN WE HAVE SOMETHING STRANGE GOING ON
-- WITH OUR BOOKING AND SHOULD ROLLBACK.

SELECT check_booked_passengers(@bid);

CALL new_contact(@bid,
                 'Göran',
                 'Greenleaf',
                 'haldir@gmail.com',
                 '+9973565677');

-- RETURNS TRUE IF BOOKING IS CORRECT

SELECT is_correct_booking(@bid);

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;

-- Part 3

-- START TRANSACTION;

LOCK TABLES ba_booking WRITE,
            ba_paid_booking WRITE,            
            ba_passenger WRITE,
            ba_flight WRITE,
            ba_flight AS ba_f WRITE,
            ba_contact WRITE,
            ba_weekday_factor WRITE,
            ba_weekly_schedule READ,
            ba_weekly_schedule AS ba_ws READ,
            ba_plane READ;

CALL pay_booking(@bid, 987654331);

COMMIT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This is an assignement for school just so that you know, I would really like to understand why I have this problem.

Comment: Please retag this with "homework"

Comment: @Marcus: Thanks.. weird the retag option has now appeared for me

Comment: Are you getting an error about ba_flight not being locked? If so, please add details. Also, please provide the engine types for the tables

Answer (score 1):

from [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables.html) about locking :

*If a session issues a LOCK TABLES statement to acquire a lock while already holding locks, its existing locks are released implicitly before the new locks are granted.*

you are acquiring double lock on "ba_flight" on the same command. Also as far as I know you can't acquire 2 write locks on the same table anyway.

Please try to remove duplicated locks on same table and try again.

Also you would better check [this documentation for locking inside transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-and-transactions.html) for the right way to lock tables.

Comment: The locks are being requested as READ locks. You have to lock for each alias used. From the manual: "You cannot refer to a locked table multiple times in a single query using the same name. Use aliases instead, and obtain a separate lock for the table and each alias"

Comment: I've just noticed the latter WRITE lock requests though :) .. but you can request more than one WRITE lock using the alias

Comment: Thank you frail for your answer. To be honest I don't really understand what you are getting at though, my knowledge of sql is quite limited. I'm guessing by the double locks you mean the:
"ba_flight READ" and "ba_flight AS ba_f READ" but as Cez comments i must do that. Also i have tried removing one of these. But if I do I get an error stating that i haven't locked that table.

I have also trie setting all locks as WRITE to no avail...